# Basic Javascript scoping

Tags: javascript, function, scope, coffeescript

I am trying to understand variable scopes. Why I can't get the ingredients value from the Utils.delay function on the html property of sandwich?

CoffeeScript:

```
supermarket = JSON.parse(Utils.domLoadScriptSync(URL))


cart = (ingredients) ->
  Utils.delay 5, ->
    ingredients = supermarket[i].name
    return ingredients
  return ingredients
cart()

sandwich = new Layer
  html: ingredients
```

Transpiled JavaScript:

```
var cart, sandwich, supermarket;

supermarket = JSON.parse(Utils.domLoadScriptSync(URL));

cart = function(ingredients) {
  Utils.delay(5, function() {
    ingredients = supermarket[i].name;
    return ingredients;
  });
  return ingredients;
};

cart();

sandwich = new Layer({
  html: ingredients
});
```

Comment: There are five `b`s. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The style of this JavaScript is really putting me off a lot. Might want to give a  look to google's [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml). But there's actually broken lines if that's supposed to be Javascript.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It's coffee. But it still doesn't explain what 'works fine' means.

Comment: I hope it's easier now guys. Sorry about that.

Comment: Nice edit Austin! It is now obvious what's wrong (to a Javascript programmer).

Answer (score 3):

I will point out the problems in the transpiled Javascript:

```
// Note that ingredients isn't declared here.
var cart, sandwich, supermarket;

supermarket = JSON.parse(Utils.domLoadScriptSync(URL));

// ingredients is actually "declared" here. It's scoped to the function as a parameter.
cart = function(ingredients) {
  // We're going to run this function *asynchronously* 5 seconds later.
  Utils.delay(5, function() {
    // Here we assign a value to the function parameter, but by this
    // point cart will have already returned its value.
    ingredients = supermarket[i].name;
    return ingredients;
  });
  // Return undefined.
  return ingredients;
};
// cart is a function that takes a parameter, but you haven't passed in anything.
// cart also returns a value, but you haven't captured the return value.
cart();

sandwich = new Layer({
  // This ingredients is an undefined variable because the other ingredients
  // is scoped to the function.
  html: ingredients
});
```

`Utils.delay` is going to delay for 5 seconds, but it's delaying asynchronously. It's going to assign a value to the `ingredients` function variable, but the `cart` function will have returned it's value before this is done. And since `ingredients` is scoped the function, the outer scope will never see the assigned `ingredients` value.

My suggestions to fix this:

- You don't need to pass in `ingredients` as a function parameter. You never use it.
- `cart` returns a value that you should capture.
- I don't know what you're trying to do with `Utils.delay`, but it's not going to work.

These are just suggestions. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I don't know if they'll work.

Answer (score 0):

So your CoffeeScript converted to JavaScript is as follows:

```
var cart, sandwich, supermarket;

supermarket = JSON.parse(Utils.domLoadScriptSync(URL));

cart = function(ingredients) {
  Utils.delay(5, function() {
    ingredients = supermarket[i].name;
    return ingredients;
  });
  return ingredients;
};

cart();

sandwich = new Layer({
  html: ingredients
});
```

It sounds like `Utils.delay` is an asynchronous function that waits `x` seconds before running.

So what happens is, when you call `cart()` it starts a timer to run the function in `Utils.delay` and then returns `ingredients`. But the function `Utils.delay` hasn't run yet so `ingredients` doesn't exist.

When the function in `Utils.delay` does run it gets the value and returns it. (Not sure what it returns to though.)

What exactly are you trying to do? What is the end goal here?

Comment: Get a value from the API, run a function and return the value to a layer html property.

Comment: What are you doing with the Layer after?

Comment: The layer will be in a loop that will check the data on the API and give it the text to the html property.

Comment: What you're trying to do requires understanding asynchronous programming in JavaScript. You'll have to read up on that to be able to do what you want.